# Quotient of Ideals in the ring of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

My textbook defines the *quotient $A:B$ of two ideals $A,B$* of a ring $R$ to be
$A:B=\{r\in R\mid rb\in A~ \forall b\in B\}$. This is equivalent to
$A:B= \{r\in R\mid rB\subseteq A\}. $

A previous exercise asked "In the ring $\mathbf{Z}$, what is $(m)(n)$?," and I proved that $(m)(n)=(mn)$.

> My current exercise asks "In the ring $\mathbf{Z}$, what is $(m):(n)$? I'm assuming this answer will be similar in form to the last one.

So far I've managed to get that if $m$ is prime then $(m)$ contains a unique element and so $(m):(n)=\{0,1\}$. I'm now stuck on how to further classify $(m):(n)$ for the integers. I'm also not really sure what kind of answer I'll be able to give.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are no integers $m\neq 0$ such that the ideal $(m)$ generated by $m$ has a unique element, and $\{0,1\}$ is not an ideal of $\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: Why don't you try some examples?  What's $(12):(3)$?  How about $(21):(6)$?

Comment: @KeenanKidwell Oh yeah, doh! My excuse is that I've been working all day!

Comment: @SpamIAm Is the answer then that $(m)(n)=(\frac{m}{n})$ if $n|m$, otherwise it's just the zero ideal?

Comment: JamesMachin: That is much closer, but it is still incorrect. Carefully work the example $(21):(6)$ that SpamIAm provided.

Comment: @JamesMachin Remember that in a PID (or more generally, in a Dedekind domain), **To contain is to divide**.  Note that $(6) \not \subseteq (21)$ since $21 \nmid 6$.  So what could you choose for $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $r(6) \subseteq (21)$?

Comment: @spamIam I'm not sure what a PID is, but maybe I have the wrong idea of the ideal generated by 6. I thought $(6)=\{0,6,12,18,\dots \}$. Therefore it couldn't be a subset of 21 because it contains "too many" elements (not exactly, but $6,12,18, \notin (21)$). I don't see how $r(6)$ could ever be a subset of $(21)$, as $21\in (21)$ and there is no $r\in \mathbf{Z}$ such that $r6=21$. Edit: I just realised how stupid that was. r(6) only needs to be contained...

Comment: @Karlkronenfeld I'm now getting $(m)(n)=(\dfrac{lcm(m,n)}{n})$ Is this correct?

Comment: @JamesMachin A PID is a principal ideal domain, an integral domain in which every ideal is principal.  The classic example is $\mathbb{Z}$.  Your edit is right on.  To contain is to divide!  What should $r$ be if $(6r) \subseteq (21)$, i.e. $21 \mid 6r$?

Comment: @SpamIAm I'd say $7$, but also all multiples of $7$. I've so far got that $(21):(6)=(7)$, $(12):(3)=(4)$, $(5):(3)=(5)$. Probably $(p):(n)=(p)$ if $p$ is prime. Is $(m)(n)=(\frac{lcm(m,n)}{n})$ then? The only thing is I'm not sure I'm allowed to talk about division in $\mathbf{Z}$?

Comment: That seems like a good conjecture.  Just as a note, you can simplify that a bit since $\text{lcm}(m,n) = \frac{mn}{\gcd(m,n)}$.  When trying to prove this conjecture, you should probably think about the prime factorizations of $m$ and $n$.  You absolutely can talk about division in $\mathbb{Z}$: by definition the lcm is divisible by $n$, so the result will still be an integer.

Comment: @spamIam Yeah I realized that I could use the gcd version instead, which made me think there would be a nice number theory way to show the equality. I'm looking for the set of all $r$ such that r(3k)=(12c) for all k and some c. I have no clue how to go about solving that though! I can show containment both ways but I'd rather use proof using number theory!

Comment: I'm still stuck ;(

Comment: If you use the prime factorization of $m$ and $n$, I think it's pretty clear.  Otherwise, let us know where you're getting stuck in the containments.

Comment: @SpamIam I can show the containments but I haven't done it via prime factorization and I really want to =(

Answer (score 3):

Let us investigate the definition $A:B = \{r\mid rB\subseteq A\}$ for $A = (m), B = (n)$.

It says that $r \in A: B$ iff $\forall x \exists y:rnx = my$. Obviously it is sufficient to find an $y_1$ for $x = 1$, since then $y_x = xy_1$.

Thus the condition to solve becomes $rn = my$, or, phrased differently, $m \mid rn$.

Now the final step is to take $n$ out of the equation by dividing by $\gcd(m,n)$: $$m \mid rn \iff \left.\frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)}~\middle\vert~ r \frac{n}{\gcd(m,n)}\right.$$
By definition of $\gcd(m,n)$, the two fractions are coprime and we are left with the defining condition: $$\frac m{\gcd(m,n)}\mid r$$

We conclude that $(m) : (n) = \left(\dfrac m{\gcd(m,n)}\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider a more general problem, with $A$ and $B$ arbitrary ideals of a commutative ring $R$. Then
$$
(A:B)=\{r\in R:rB\subseteq A\}
$$
Let's try our hand with
$$
(A:A+B)=\{r\in R:r(A+B)\subseteq A\}
$$
If $r\in (A:B)$, then $r(A+B)\subseteq rA+rB\subseteq A+A=A$, so $r\in(A:A+B)$. Conversely, if $r\in(A:A+B)$, then $rB\subseteq r(A+B)\subseteq A$, so $r\in(A:B)$.

Thus your problem is finding
$$\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}
(m\Z:n\Z)=(m\Z:(m\Z+n\Z))=(m\Z:d\Z)
$$
where $d=\gcd(m,n)$.

The task is now much easier, because $m\Z\subseteq d\Z$. Saying that $r\in(m\Z:d\Z)$ is equivalent to saying that $rd\in m\Z$, that is,
$$
rd=mk
$$
for some $k$, which in turn is
$$
r=\frac{m}{d}k
$$
so $r\in(m/d)\Z$.

Therefore
$$
(m\Z:n\Z)=\frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)}\Z
$$